Can't link idp user automatically
I would like that only users who already have a Keycloak account with the same e-mail address (user name) can log in via the idp.
Keycloak already has documentation here on how the authentication flow should look. Unfortunately, this does not work for me.
I have activated the “Login with email” option in the realm settings and all users in Keycloak have an email as their username.
It's about Openid connect with Microsoft Azure.
My authentication flow configuration
I get this error when I log in
Why is this happening?
I have tried various authentication flows. Unfortunately without success.

I have found a solution. With the following mapper, the user is automatically assigned based on the e-mail:

